# 'seaborn-whitegrid' is not a valid package style, path of style file

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, data-analysis

I'm trying to use a levelshift detector from adtk package and been following an example given in their documentation. The problem is I'm always getting the following error.

This is my code

```
import seaborn as sns
from adtk.detector import LevelShiftAD
from adtk.visualization import plot

level_shift_ad=LevelShiftAD(c=6.0, side='both', window=12)
anomalies=level_shift_ad.fit_detect(dft2)
plot(s, anomaly=anomalies, anomaly_color='red')
```

The error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\ricac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\style\core.py:137, in use(style)
    136 try:
--> 137     style = _rc_params_in_file(style)
    138 except OSError as err:

File c:\Users\ricac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:879, in _rc_params_in_file(fname, transform, fail_on_error)
    878 rc_temp = {}
--> 879 with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
    880     try:

File c:\Users\ricac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py:137, in _GeneratorContextManager.__enter__(self)
    136 try:
--> 137     return next(self.gen)
    138 except StopIteration:

File c:\Users\ricac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:856, in _open_file_or_url(fname)
    855 fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
--> 856 with open(fname, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    857     yield f

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'seaborn-whitegrid'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
    142             f"styles are listed in `style.available`)") from err
    143 filtered = {}
    144 for k in style:  # don't trigger RcParams.__getitem__('backend')

OSError: 'seaborn-whitegrid' is not a valid package style, path of style file, URL of style file, or library style name (library styles are listed in `style.available`)
```

It says that the style `whitegrid` is not available, but when I check for the styles available I get:

```
plt.style.available
['Solarize_Light2',
 '_classic_test_patch',
 '_mpl-gallery',
 '_mpl-gallery-nogrid',
 'bmh',
 'classic',
 'dark_background',
 'fast',
 'fivethirtyeight',
 'ggplot',
 'grayscale',
 'seaborn-v0_8',
 'seaborn-v0_8-bright',
 'seaborn-v0_8-colorblind',
 'seaborn-v0_8-dark',
 'seaborn-v0_8-dark-palette',
 'seaborn-v0_8-darkgrid',
 'seaborn-v0_8-deep',
 'seaborn-v0_8-muted',
 'seaborn-v0_8-notebook',
 'seaborn-v0_8-paper',
 'seaborn-v0_8-pastel',
 'seaborn-v0_8-poster',
 'seaborn-v0_8-talk',
 'seaborn-v0_8-ticks',
 'seaborn-v0_8-white',
 'seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid',
 'tableau-colorblind10']
```

If I choose the 'seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid' I get an error message saying I must choose between white, dark, whitegrid, darkgrid, ticks

I tried to run this code and was expecting to get a plot with the changepoints marked